# Release the focus from my window

Tags: windows, pyqt4

I'm wondering how I can give the focus back to the window that it before my window got it. I've looked around and so far only seen functions to get, not release, focus.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you just need the focus released, or do you need to focus on another entity instead, after releasing the focus from said entity?

Comment: My thought is that focus works like a stack, and if my window loose the focus the last window that had the focus should regain it. So I just need to loose the focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know previous widget in your form [tab order](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qwidget.html#setTabOrder), take a look at [QWidget::nextInFocusChain](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#nextInFocusChain) and [QWidget::previousInFocusChain](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwidget.html#previousInFocusChain). You should be able to get next\previous widget in your widget's focus chain. Once you know it, you can pass focus to it.

If you're looking to get next\previous window in [Z-order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#zorder) take a look at winapi [GetNextWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function (GW_HWNDPREV in wCmd parameter will return a handle to the window above the given window). Once you know the previous window you can bring it back to from using [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Well, I don't control the other window, It could be a browser or anything else. I don't need to know what it is, I just need to give it back the focus my application took.